# Making a shared library from existing object files

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries

I have a project in my IDE. I need to make a shared library of it to use in extensions. I don't want to make a copy of this project with shared-library settings. Is there any way to build a shared library using the object files (.o) from my already existing project? As I understand, I can write a makefile for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you're on some sort of Unix and are probably using the GNU toolchain. In that case, to create a proper shared library, you'd need to compile your code using the position-independent code flags (-fpic or -fPIC) before you can create a shared library. Unless your .o files are already compiled with those flags, chances are you won't end up with a working shared lib.

If they already are compiled for position independent code, the usual `g++ -shared ...` should do the trick.

Comment: @pajton - Guess who's been caught out by this before :).

Answer (score 9):

`g++ -shared -fPIC -o myshared.so *.o`

Comment: Why use -fPIC and -shared in same line?